# Get the "Firstname"-Property for Exchange Online/Cloud accounts (via PS)

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange

Creating an account via PS on ExchangeOnline you can set the [first and last name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps):

```
New-Mailbox -Name 'Test' -FirstName Test1 -LastName Test2 ...
```

Are those properties saved (if not what are they used for)? I can't find them through `Get-Mailbox Test | select *`.

Comment: If you you downvote please leave a comment, on how to improve the question. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this question does not demonstrate any research or effort on your part as the asker. This information is pretty basic and well documented. You don't get a full report of attributes when you just run the get-cmdlet, but a specific subset. This is common for many cmdlet as is the means of viewing all attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In this case the problem with research is the type of problem. It wasn't a lack of research but a lack of relevant results. I assumed Firstname is a property of of Mailbox so searching for `get-mailbox firstname lastname` together puts you on an even worse track, e.g. through this one: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/manage-user-mailboxes Of course, after you know there's an user object involved the search gets pretty easy in retrospective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command to get firstname, lastname properties:

```
Get-Mailbox user01 | Get-User| select firstname,lastname
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. So the users are objects within the AD and the mailboxes objects within the exchange server?! How exactly do they relate to one another? If I understand correctly they are "connected" via the UserPrincipalName?